# Register MetadataBuilderContributor based on database type in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I added a few implementations of `MetadataBuilderContributor` based on the database (h2, mysql, oracle) since they all have a slightly different syntax.

As of now, registering of the contributors works through the property in `application.yml`:

```yaml
spring:  
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        metadata_builder_contributor: org.foo.bar.H2Implementation
```

I am aware that I can create multiple profiles -h2, -mysql, -oracle to apply the correct contributors. However, I'd like to automatically set these based on the `driverClassName` that was set (if I can find a match, otherwise default to the application.yml)

Is there a way to do this and not require the entry in my application.yml?

Comment: Do you find a solution to this ? Thanks

Comment: Hey @antoine.lange, we added an application listener (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/event/ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent.html) and on `onApplicationEvent` we're reading the environment variables and based on this set the contributor accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution that Frame91 mentioned, using a Spring `ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent`

```
public class MetadataBuilderContributerResolver
    implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent>
{
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent event) {
        ConfigurableEnvironment environment = event.getEnvironment();
        String driverClassName = environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.driverClassName");

        Class<?> metadataBuilderContributorClazz = switch (driverClassName) {
            case "org.h2.Driver" -> H2MetadataBuilderContributor.class;
            case "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver" -> MariaDbMetadataBuilderContributor.class;
            case "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" -> OracleMetadataBuilderContributor.class;
            default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported driver: " + driverClassName);
        };

        String className = metadataBuilderContributorClazz.getName();

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.metadata_builder_contributor", className);
        environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(new PropertiesPropertySource(this.getClass().getName(), props));
    }
}
```

Thanks to Frame91

Comment: Looking good! We also have "legacy" drivers in our switch/case, such as oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver which is deprecated in favor of oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver. Maybe you want to include this one as well if it fits your use-case.